# Android Management API: How to wipe a dedicated device not from EMM console?

Tags: android, google-apis-explorer, android-management-api

Is there any way to wipe a dedicated device, not from EMM console, but straightly from the device, by a passcode or smth else?

Comment: I meant besides [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/blob/master/clients/1.28.0/google-api-services-androidmanagement/v1/com/google/api/services/androidmanagement/v1/AndroidManagement.java#L806).

Answer (score 1):

That's possible. First, you should get list of devices like this:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun listDevices(enterpriseName: String): List<Device>? {
    return androidManagementClient
        .enterprises()
        .devices()
        .list(enterpriseName)
        .execute()
        ?.devices
}
```

Then you should compare `Device.hardwareInfo.serialNumber` with serialNumber of your device, and if it's there - pass `Device.name` to the method `delete(java.lang.String name)`, that you've mentioned. I've tried it on the provisioned device and after this operation it performed reboot and reset to factory settings on its own, so be ready for this.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of this, anyway thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the device **is not** in lock task mode (aka kiosk mode) you can trigger a factory reset from Settings.

If the device **is** in lock task mode (which I suspect is your case) there is no native way to exit lock task mode from the device or to trigger a factory reset.

However you can implement it yourself in an app that you own and install on the device:

1. Make this app available in lock task mode (you can allow multiple apps in lock task mode, see [kiosk launcher](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices#kiosk-launcher))
2. In this app ask the user for a password, or any other authentication method
3. After authentication expose a button to wipe the device
4. When the user taps this button, send a request to your EMM server and wipe the device via the Android Management API

The only caveat of that approach is that it requires the device to be connected to the network, it doesn't work offline.

Comment: Thank you, sadly, but it looks like the only way.